# How can I add another button in Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and Im trying to rebuild the demo app. How can I add the FloatingActioButton to the App it seems that I can't add another body or something.  How can I do this ?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  int _counter = 0;

  void increase_Counter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter += 1;
    });
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Your press button $_counter times"),)
      body:(FloatingActionButton(onPressed: increase_Counter,)
    ),)
    ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below code. Floating action button always goes inside scaffold.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Your press button $_counter times"),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
    
 
    );
  }
```

And you can also follow [FloatingActionButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) to get better understanding.